# What are the best e-commerce modules/setups?

Tags: 7, theming, commerce

Googling for "Drupal E-commerce" brings up a ton of old results, and I wanted to weed out all the garbage. I'm a regular on SO but I thought that I might get better insight/advice here.

Running Drupal 7.9 (multiple sites will be installed but running their own Drupal install), what e-commerce packages should I install (shopping cart and payment options)?
What are the pitfalls to look out for?
What theme do you suggest, that is geared towards E-commerce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not yet built an e-commerce site on D7, so I cannot get really specific.

That said, the obvious starting point for e-commerce on Drupal 7 is the [Drupal Commerce](http://drupal.org/project/commerce) package. Just start with the basic package, see if it fits your needs, and install add-ons if you need them. There even is a dedicated [Drupal Commerce website](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/) with documentation, a forum and more.

There are a couple of themes that are specifically geared towards e-commerce, for instance [Acquia Prosper](http://drupal.org/project/acquia_prosper) and [AT Commerce](http://drupal.org/project/at-commerce).

Answer (score 3):

The Ubercart module for Drupal 6 was always a winner for me.

That said the Commerce module does look very promising but I have yet to try it out fully.

The Ubertcart module for Drupal 7 is coming along wonderfully too, so either this or the Commerce module would be suitable, but I would hint towards starting with the Commerce module as it's a dedicated Drupal 7 e-commerce solution and has some good themes to start with too as pointed out by marcvangend.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try checking out [Martplug](http://drupal.org/project/martplug).  It's a complete distribution that contains Drupal Commerce and a load of other gubbins to get you off the ground!  I've only played around with it, not used it in production yet..but still looks pretty neat!

With regards to themes, [Omega](http://www.drupal.org/project/omega) is a great starting point (and also encompases responsive design)..and if you combine it with the [Context](http://www.drupal.org/project/context) and [Delta](http://www.drupal.org/project/delta) modules then it's a surefire win!

Comment: Yes, +1 for Omega as base theme, even though its not specifically meant for e-commerce.